# ng-show with CSS fader not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to implement the second solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424877/how-can-i-fade-in-and-out-the-visibility-of-a-div-using-ng-show-with-angularjs-1) to get text to fade up on `ng-show`. My HTML is:

```
<input ng-focus="hasFocus = true" ng-blur="hasFocus = false"
       type="text" placeholder="Click to fade"/>
<p ng-show="hasFocus" class="fader">Fade me</p>
```

My CSS is:

```
.fader.ng-show {
    transition: all linear 500ms;
    opacity: 1;
}

.fader.ng-hide {
    transition: all linear 500ms;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

and my Angular is:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

A JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/os4dr5dp/8/).

Comment: But the first answer has more upvotes, it works perfectly: http://plnkr.co/edit/HWi0FfDOsHeSOkcrRtN2?p=preview

Comment: I think you are missing `ngAnimate` here

Comment: @NishantDixit When I add that, the text always displays, regardless of what I press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did same which you are looking but I never use `ngAnimate` in angular so I took sample code from your reference link of stackoverflow question and add `fader.ng-hide-remove` and `add` class now It is working fine, Hope this will satisfy your condition.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

```css
.fader.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fader.ng-hide-remove,
.fader.ng-hide-add {
  display: block !important;
}

.fader.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: all linear 1000ms;
}

.fader.ng-hide-add {
  transition: all linear 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<input ng-focus="hasFocus = true" ng-blur="hasFocus = false" type="text" placeholder="Click to fade"/>
<p ng-show="hasFocus" class="fader">Fade me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-hide` class sets `display: none!important`.

Override with it with `display: block!important;`

### The DEMO

```css
.fader{
    transition: all linear 500ms;
    opacity: 1;
}

.fader.ng-hide {
    display: block!important;
    transition: all linear 500ms;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
   <button ng-click="hasFocus=!hasFocus">
      Click me
   </button>
   <p ng-show="hasFocus" class="fader">Fade me</p>
</body>
```

Comment: How would you get the text to fade in too? I prefer your answer because it doesn't use ngAnimate, but when I run it, the show transition doesn't work.